# Camel cxfrs with XML

Tags: xml, apache-camel, cxfrs

The website that I'm trying to access sends xml only. With Camel's XML DSL I'm trying to get that XML and send it off to another site via cxrfs. For right now I can settle for it going to a bean and merely being able to access the data.

When I execute my route I dont necessarily get any errors. It just doesnt do anything with the XML probably because its not getting stored in the body. Not sure though.

**Output**

```
[INFO] Starting Camel ...
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] MainSupport                    INFO  Apache Camel 2.12.0.redhat-610379 starting
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] SpringCamelContext             INFO  Apache Camel 2.12.0.redhat-610379 (CamelContext: camel) is starting
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] ManagedManagementStrategy      INFO  JMX is enabled
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] DefaultTypeConverter           INFO  Loaded 190 type converters
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] SpringCamelContext             INFO  AllowUseOriginalMessage is enabled. If access to the original message is not needed, then its recommended to turn this option off as it may improve performance.
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] SpringCamelContext             INFO  StreamCaching is not in use. If using streams then its recommended to enable stream caching. See more details at http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] SpringCamelContext             INFO  Route: route1 started and consuming from: Endpoint[timer://foo?repeatCount=1]
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] SpringCamelContext             INFO  Total 1 routes, of which 1 is started.
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] SpringCamelContext             INFO  Apache Camel 2.12.0.redhat-610379 (CamelContext: camel) started in 0.335 seconds
[camel) thread #0 - timer://foo] BusApplicationContext          INFO  Refreshing org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusApplicationContext@3fd43e1d: startup date [Fri Sep 19 09:33:45 EDT 2014]; parent: org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext@375d661b
[camel) thread #0 - timer://foo] idationXmlBeanDefinitionReader INFO  Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml]
[camel) thread #0 - timer://foo] idationXmlBeanDefinitionReader INFO  Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [META-INF/cxf/camel/cxf-extension-camel.xml]
My Processor! Get In
null
My Processor! Get out
Message: [Body is null]
```

**Route**

```
<bean id="proc" class="com.b2bservicep1.httpserv.Proc"/>

<camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route>
        <from uri="timer://foo?repeatCount=1"/>
       <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpMethod">
            <constant>GET</constant>
        </setHeader>
        <to uri="cxfrs://http://myxmlsitethatimcalling.com?resourceClasses=com.b2bservicep1.httpserv.Proc"/>
        <to uri="bean:proc?method=process"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>

</beans>
```

**Processor that I wrote**

```
package com.b2bservicep1.httpserv;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;

import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;

public class Proc implements Processor{

    @Override @GET
    public void process(Exchange arg0) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("My Processor! Get In");
        System.out.println(arg0.getIn().getBody());
        System.out.println("My Processor! Get out");
        System.out.println(arg0.getOut());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify more than just one Method header. Here is an example

```
@Test
public void testGetCustomerWithCxfRsEndpoint() {
    Exchange exchange 
        = template.send("cxfrs://http://localhost:" + getPort1() + "/" + getClass().getSimpleName() + "/?httpClientAPI=true", new Processor() {
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                exchange.setPattern(ExchangePattern.InOut);
                Message inMessage = exchange.getIn();
                // set the Http method
                inMessage.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, "GET");
                // set the relative path
                inMessage.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_PATH, "/customerservice/customers/123");                
                // Specify the response class , cxfrs will use InputStream as the response object type 
                inMessage.setHeader(CxfConstants.CAMEL_CXF_RS_RESPONSE_CLASS, Customer.class);
                // since we use the Get method, so we don't need to set the message body
                inMessage.setBody(null);                
            }
        });

    // get the response message 
    Customer response = (Customer) exchange.getOut().getBody();
    assertNotNull("The response should not be null ", response);
    assertEquals("Get a wrong customer id ", String.valueOf(response.getId()), "123");
    assertEquals("Get a wrong customer name", response.getName(), "John");
    assertEquals("Get a wrong response code", 200, exchange.getOut().getHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE));
}
```

You can find more information about how to use camel-cxfrs producer in [this unit test](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-cxf/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/cxf/jaxrs/CxfRsProducerTest.java).